# How verifies nullable and nonnull in a ios `.m` files

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

How to make `.m` files verify nullable and nonnull in Xcode, just like in `.h`

Swift can judge optional values very well, but OC does not. OC can prompt that a parameter is nullable or nonnull in `.h` file, but there is no warning prompt in `.m` file, is there any way for Xcode to prompt nullable and nonnull in `.m` file?

Thanks.